# Inline code with pointers and memory explanation

Tags: c

This was part of a code that is meant to dump the stack and show its layout in a book that was written years ago. Compile this code with `-m32` (32bit) to avoid any warnings (Why?). I couldn't understand the below line, and since he doesn't cover that I come to ask StackOverflow.

- What does the author try to achieve by this line?

```c
unsigned int a, *x;
x = (unsigned int *) ((unsigned int) &a & ~0xf); // ..What?
```

By the way, if someone could name the above line and get a better **title** for me...

Comment: This code won't actively "dump the stack", but I guess it could be used to calculate the start of the stack segment in some scenario. It just takes the address of `a`, which is a variable on the stack, zeroes the low 4 bits, and stores the result in `x`. Almost as if it's calculating the address of the beginning of the stack segment, perhaps.

Comment: @jarmod Not these two lines of code, that's not what I meant. This is _part_ of.

Comment: Using `unsigned int` is wrong because it may not be large enough to represent the pointer -- it should be `uintptr_t`. The code is rounding down the address of `a` to the nearest multiple of 16, and storing the result in `x`.

Comment: @SayNoToWhiteBoys would you mind adding more context around what's being done and why? Say a longer snippet of code and/or other information the author might have mentioned. I mean it as a complement to the question so that other people (specially people that have similar doubts in the future) have more context around what's going on. I wouldn't change the current content per se, I think the best approach would be adding an _appendix_ section.

Comment: @WilkMaia Well the code has more lines but they _don't_ really effect my question. But [there you go](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/stack-layout.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect the assignment:

- `&a` is the address of `a`.
- `(unsigned int) &a` casts it to an unsigned integer.
- `0xf` is an integer with the binary value `0...01111`.
- `~0xf` is the bitwise complement of this, yielding all ones but the least four (`1...10000`).
- `((unsigned int) &a & ~0xf)` sets the least four bits of the address of a to zero by the "and" operator `&`. This will give you the address smaller than or equal to `a`'s address that is divisible by 16 (0x10).
- `(unsigned int *) ((unsigned int) &a & ~0xf)` casts this result back to a pointer to an unsigned integer.
- `x = (unsigned int *) ((unsigned int) &a & ~0xf);` is the final assignment.

The intermediate cast is done, because the operator `&` works only with integers, not with pointers.

For example, if `a`'s address is 0x123456, then `x` will receive 0x123450.

*Why* specifically this is done, I cannot say because the context is missing.

These casts only work as intended if the sizes of pointers and integers match. If you use another system, it will not necessarily work.

Comment: Thanks, but why do we need to cast memory addresses to an unsigned integer?

Comment: Also, why 64bit compilation yields a couple of warnings, and the 32bit isn't? I.e `warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size`

Comment: About casting: the `&` operator cannot be used on pointer types, that's why. About the warning: on 32-bit systems it's expected that pointer size is 32 bits long, while on 64-bit systems it's 64 bits longs. If you tried to cast that to an `unsigned int` (usually 32 bits long) you'd get a warning because you might be losing data.

Comment: For reference on the latter you can check https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=environments-ilp32-lp64-data-models-data-type-sizes

Comment: The correct data type would be `uintptr_t` instead of `unsigned int`. On a 64-bit system, `unsigned int` may be smaller than a pointer. Generally, such a manipulation of a pointer is undefined behavior. It *may* give a useful (implementation-defined) result on a specific platform.